# basic variable scope in php

Tags: php, xml

Using MVC I have a model directory inside of which are two files; menu.xml and the following model.php.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('menu.xml');
print_r ($xml);
?>
```

In my views directory I have an index.php files as follows:

```
<?php
include '../model/model.php';
print_r($xml);
foreach ($xml->children() as $option)
{    
?>  
    <li><a href='<?= $option->getName() ?>'><?= $option['name'] ?></li>
<?php 
}
?>
</ul>
```

In another directory - this time html - i have the following:

```
<!-- This is the controller -->

<?php

require_once('../includes/helpers.php');
// determine which page to render

if (isset($_GET['page'])) 
    $page = $_GET['page'];
else 
    $page = 'index';

// show page
switch ($page)
{
    case 'index';
        render('templates/header', array('title' => 'Main Menu'));
        render('index');
        render('templates/footer');
        break;
}
?>
```

This is supposed to show a list of the children of the menu.xml file.  If I access model.php directly:

```
<pre>
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('menu.xml');
print_r ($xml);
?>
</pre>
```

I can see the contents of the $xml object.

So why doesn't the `include '../model/model.php` command work?

Any tips appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with "variable scope". As a tip for the future, it could also have been illustrated with a much simpler example, which would help you and others see where the problem lies more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('menu.xml');
```

This path is relative to the current executed script. That’s why it works when your accessing `model/model.php` directly, but not when including it from `./index.php`. Use absolute path instead:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(__DIR__ . '/menu.xml');
```

**Edit by [IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop)**:

For PHP versions [older than 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(dirname(__FILE__) . '/menu.xml');
```

Comment: Note that for older versions of PHP (I think anything before 5.3, but could be wrong) there is no `__DIR__`, but you can get the same value with `dirname(__FILE__)`. Also, the same should be used for the `include` lines themselves, rather than relying on `../` having the right meaning, as "current directory" can be a slippery concept in some cases.